# Selected Image from UIImagePickerController not showing up in UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to display a selected image from a UIImagePickerController inside a collectionViewCell that is holding a UIImageView. I am able to open and load the imagePicker, but when I select an image the UIImageView still has the hard original placeholder image. I believe it has something to do with passing the selectedImage into the actual cell, and not to the loginController, but I am not sure. Thanks in advance for any help!

// loginCell class
class LoginCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imagefile")
    //...
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImage)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}()

var loginController: LoginController?

func handleSelectProfileImage() {
    guard let loginController = delegate as? LoginController else {
        return
    }
    loginController.showImagePicker()
}
```

}

// login controller class
class LoginController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, LoginControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
weak var loginCollectionView: UICollectionView!

func showImagePicker() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromImagePicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromImagePicker = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromImagePicker = originalImage
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromImagePicker {
        loginCell.profileImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let loginCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loginCellId, for: indexPath) as! LoginCell
        loginCell.delegate = self
        return loginCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `LoginCell` here:

```
if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromImagePicker {
    let loginCell = LoginCell()
    loginCell.profileImageView.image = selectedImage
}
```

You should remove the second line, so you are using your class variable named `loginCell` and not the local one, which is, according to your code, is not shown anywhere.

```
if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromImagePicker {
    loginCell.profileImageView.image = selectedImage
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually did try that and same thing happened. I added my cellForRowAtIndexPath method where I set the loginCell as the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Set image of loginCdell in completion of dismissblock of imagePickerController:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

var selectedImageFromImagePicker: UIImage?

if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
    selectedImageFromImagePicker = editedImage
} else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
    selectedImageFromImagePicker = originalImage
}


dismiss(animated: true, completion:{
if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromImagePicker {
    loginCell.profileImageView.image = selectedImage
}
})
}
```

Comment: thanks, logic makes sense - but still not showing selected image in profileImageView on dismiss.

Comment: whether you are creating your instance of logincell in viewWillAppear.hen make it in viewDidLoad